# What is the kaffara on a bank loan with interest over the last two years?

Tags: riba, kaffarah

I took a bank loan for education and have been paying interest for the last two years. What is the kaffara for this sin?

Please enlighten in the light of Quran and Hadith.

Comment: If I was in your shoes, I would pay Sadaqa (for the poor) with an equivalent amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no Kaffara (Delete) for Usury** , means you just need to **ask forgiveness and repent** 
  And try not to do it as you can .